# Getting error on server Cannot be null Parameter name root

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, error-handling, ninject

I am getting a error on server (on localhost its working fine)
I have tried with a normal [html page](http://gcms.microlent.com/my.html), but its giving same exception for that also.

Error:
[image]

Note:application is built using asp.net mvc3, c#, sql server 2008, ninject, nhibernate.

I am not able to understand root cause of error. Please guide/provide help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue.. the issue was because of low trust level set on webserver for webapplication